# Improve time with multi thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I had some issue
I had  data list with format like this :

```
json_list = [{
            "code": "001123",
            "phone_number": "1229992XXX",
            "email": "foo@email.com",
            "address": "address_fake_1",
            "note": "note dummy "
        }, {}, {}, {} ...
]
```

length more than 23.000 +

```
marking = ["654564", "hj876", "8768"..., .....]
```

length more than 3000 +

And I wanna try to eliminate making and json_list  to get data by searching for the same data by code from json_list.
But in my concern need take time more than 20 minutes to eliminate.
I used **threading** to solve that issue. but still take a long time.
Can any one some help me for that issue?.

This my code

```
def find_marking(x=None, y=None):
    text_match = SequenceMatcher(None, x, y.get('code')).ratio()
    if text_match == 1 or (0.98 <= text_match < 0.99): return y
    return None

def eliminate_marking(marking_list=None, json_list=None)->tuple:
    result,result_mark = [], []

    def __process_eliminate(marking=None, data_scrap=None):
        for a in range(0, math.ceil(len(data_scrap)/100)):
            if len(data_scrap[a * 100:(a + 1) * 100]) > 0:
                for data in data_scrap[a * 100:(a + 1) * 100]:
                    result_data = find_marking(marking, data)
                    if result_data  :
                        data_scrap.pop(0)
                        result_mark.append(marking)
                        result.append(result_data)
                        return

    threads = []
    for marking in marking_list:
        th = threading.Thread(target=__process_eliminate, kwargs={'marking':marking,
                                                                'data_scrap': json_list})
        th.start()
        threads.append(th)
    
    for thread in threads: thread.join()

    return result_mark, result
```

Comment: Threading can't make CPU-bound processing work any faster because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)

Comment: Do you have idea solutions to solve it?

Comment: @dimassetiawan multiprocessing is better suited to CPU intensive code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use Python's multiprocessing library, which can create separate processes instead of threads. Each process will have its own memory space, helping avoid data conflicts. Here's an example:

```
import math
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

json_list = [  # Your JSON list ]
marking = ["654564", "hj876", "8768", ...]  # Your marking list

def find_marking(x, y):
    text_match = SequenceMatcher(None, x, y['code']).ratio()
    if text_match == 1 or (0.98 <= text_match < 0.99):
        return y
    return None

def eliminate_marking(marking_list, json_list):
    manager = Manager()
    result_mark = manager.list()
    result = manager.list()

    def __process_eliminate(marking, data_scrap, result_mark, result):
        for data in data_scrap:
            result_data = find_marking(marking, data)
            if result_data:
                data_scrap.remove(data)
                result_mark.append(marking)
                result.append(result_data)
                return

    processes = []
    chunk_size = 100
    num_processes = math.ceil(len(marking_list) / chunk_size)

    for i in range(num_processes):
        start_idx = i * chunk_size
        end_idx = min((i + 1) * chunk_size, len(marking_list))
        sub_marking_list = marking_list[start_idx:end_idx]

        p = Process(
            target=__process_eliminate,
            args=(sub_marking_list, json_list[:], result_mark, result)
        )
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    manager.shutdown()  # Closing the manager after the processes have completed
    return list(result_mark), list(result)

eliminated_markings, eliminated_data = eliminate_marking(marking, json_list)
```

This code uses the **multiprocessing** library to parallelize the elimination process, creating multiple processes to work on chunks of the marking list. It also uses a **Manager** to create shared data structures (**result_mark** and **result**) across processes to store the results.

Comment: It is my own works.

Comment: Do you know what happens if you don't close a multiprocessing.Manager ?

Comment: It would start consuming my system's resources which might impact its performance. Data corruptions could occur too

Comment: So why don't you close it?

Comment: python would automatically handle when program exits